# Proportionally decrease values in a list to meet a target sum

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Consider a list of integer values

```
[30, 50, 100, 50, 30]
```

Their total sum is 260. A new "target" sum is desired, e.g. 200. What would be a good way of proportionally decreasing the values in the list to achieve the new sum? The values should remain integer.

Obviously, one could decrease them by the ratio of target sum - 200/260 = 0.77 (approximately) and cast the results to integers:

```
[23, 38, 77, 38, 23]
```

New sum: 199. Almost there! Perhaps, reduce the diff from a random element?

I hope this is a sufficient explanation of the problem. However, the current approach seems a bit imperfect to me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Proportional to each other? Then that would be the correct way. 
I would use the random difference, there really isn't any other way, unless you want to deal with floats. ortional to each other? Then that would be the correct way. I think you might want to clarify what you are trying to do (give some context). That will help reach a "perfect" answer.

Comment: The ratios between elements should be similar between two lists. 30/50 ≈ 23/38. Context: it is a biological simulation and those values represent different types of agents, whose numbers should increase/decrease proportionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the "values after the dot", i.e. the remainders from integer division:

In your example:

Perfectly proportional values (each element multiplied by 200/260):

[23.076923076923077, 38.46153846153846, 76.92307692307692, 38.46153846153846, 23.076923076923077]

Remainders:

[0.07692307692307665, 0.4615384615384599, 0.9230769230769198, 0.4615384615384599, 0.07692307692307665]

If you just cut the remainders (i.e. round down to int), you are left with 2 units to distribute, assign to the 2 numbers that have the largest remainders. Here it would be the 76 and one from 38's (you need to break the tie between them, which is a bit inelegant).

So the final solution is:

[23, 39, 77, 38, 23]

This aims at minimizing the difference between the final integer values and the "perfect split" values.

A similar trick is used in genetic algorithms, it's called "remainder stochastic sampling" and the leftover values are distributed randomly, with the probability proportional to the remainders.

Answer (score 0):

Say your exponential factor is p. You want to solve for:

2*30p+2*50p^2+100p^3 = 200

I will let you solve for p.

EDIT: If you want the decreases to be proportional, solve for this:

2*p + 2*p^2 + p^3 = 260 -200 =60

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Rafał Dowgird

```
sum_1 = [20, 30, 80, 90, 100]

a = float(sum(sum_1))

b = float(Desired Sum)

total = 0

for i in range(0, len(sum_2)):
    total += sum_1[i] * (b/a)

print total
```